# "Area of interest": a physical area or a research area?

Tags: phrase-usage

> ....will help me to explore in my area of interest.

By "area of interest", I mean a research area, something like quantum physics or fluid dynamics. Is this right, or is there a better expression? Because I know *area of interest* can mean a geographical location.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with saying, "Quantum physics and quantum computing are my areas of interest." The word _area_ can refer to a geographical area, geometric area, local area, or something more abstract, like a research area.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase ***an area of interest*** is a good usage, as J.R.'s commented. Here is one of the definitions of the word "field" as defined by [the Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/field_3),

> B2 [C] **an area of activity or interest:**
>     *the field of history/science/medicine*
>     *Are you still in the same field (= are you doing the same type of work)?*

To ensure you that the phrase *area of interest* doesn't have to tie with geographical meaning, here are some examples I found in the COCA corpus,

> *Then peruse the Bureau of Labor Statistics' Occupational Outlook Handbook to learn about prospects for jobs in your **area of interest**.*
>   
>   *Another option is for school faculty or parents to arrange a visit for students with LD and/or ADD/ADHD to visit freshman college classrooms as early in their high school career as possible, with follow-up discussions with students and faculty on campus in **areas of interest**.*
>   
>   *Comprehension of sentences that are complex because of grammatical elements of difficulty (e.g., passive, pronominal, or reflexive) has been **an area of interest** in studies of children who present with language impairment (Montgomery &; Evans, 2009).*
>   
>   ***One area of interest*** within this broad area is the psychological response to pain on the part of athletes.